# Change Command line Vim Color Scheme to be like GVim

Tags: vim

Basically the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100195/change-gvim-color-scheme-to-be-like-command-line-vim), with the detail, that I know how to add new schemes, however I am hoping that there is some built in colorscheme or that I can extract it from some of the vim files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins like [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) can take the GUI color definitions and convert them to a closely matching 256-color `cterm` color palette for high-color terminals. This helps with colorschemes that otherwise only pick from the bland default 16-color terminal color palette, or only provide GUI color definitions.

Another approach is taken by [csexact](https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact), which modifies the (supported) terminal's palette to exactly match Vim's GUI colors.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the vimrc in the answer:
[What is in your .vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164847/what-is-in-your-vimrc)

Copy the following to your .vimrc:

```
" Favorite Color Scheme
if has("gui_running")
   colorscheme inkpot
   " Remove Toolbar
   set guioptions-=T
   "Terminus is AWESOME
   set guifont=Terminus\ 9
else
   colorscheme metacosm
endif

"{{{Theme Rotating
let themeindex=0
function! RotateColorTheme()
   let y = -1
   while y == -1
      let colorstring = "inkpot#ron#blue#elflord#evening#koehler#murphy#pablo#desert#torte#"
      let x = match( colorstring, "#", g:themeindex )
      let y = match( colorstring, "#", x + 1 )
      let g:themeindex = x + 1
      if y == -1
         let g:themeindex = 0
      else
         let themestring = strpart(colorstring, x + 1, y - x - 1)
         return ":colorscheme ".themestring
      endif
   endwhile
endfunction
" }}}

" Rotate Color Scheme <F8>
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :execute RotateColorTheme()<CR>
```

If you use this vimrc, then you can change your colorscheme using `F8` key, choose what you like.